# Нужно срастить [деревья]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

- Метка [дерево](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be): 246 вопросов
- метка [tree](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree): 122 вопроса

Нужно синонимизировать, основная метка - "дерево"

Comment: А [tag:деревья] для кого? // cc @αλεχολυτ

Comment: @Qwertiy какие предложения?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я думаю тоже с [tag:дерево] синонимизировать, "дерево" - основная метка.

Comment: [Готово](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be/synonyms)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а мы разве не множественное число обычно делаем основным?